# Why don't javascript function join() work?

Tags: javascript, arrays, mutation

I have an array named res2 looks like below

```
[ ' sh', '1119', '' ]
```

My purpose is to join these elements into one element. So I joined it

```
res2.join();
```

but it didn't work

```
[ ' sh', '1119', '' ]
```

Anyone knows the reason and solution for the situation?

Comment: `join()` does not modify the original array. if you did `res2 = res2.join()`, then res2 will be reassigned to a string

Comment: This worked for me.  What output do you expect and what are you actually getting?

Comment: What I want for output was the string type `'sh1119'` (not an array) and it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Array.prototype.join()` will not mutate the original array, but it will return a new string:

```
var res2 = [ ' sh', '1119', '' ];
var result = res2.join(); //" sh,1119,"
//res2 is still the array
```

Comment: Which is the comment of @therobinkim . 

Comment: Thanks, I forgot the join function returns a new string!